# parameters/fields for odoo's default change password form for update

Tags: python, api, passwords

for an existing mobile app i want to create api through controller to communicate with odoo, i know about login fields/parameters

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0","params":{"db":"odoodb","login":"myemail@smtpserver.com","password":"admin123"}}
```

for which api already have created, but now i want to know about odoo's default change password form's fields/parameters for PUT method,  please help. using odoo 14.
regards

Comment: what fields i should pass to api for odoo's own default password change mechanism? please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this url to change the password of the user.

> But the user must be logged to an Odoo session in the request headers

```
http://localhost:8069/my/security
```

You can send the params through GET or POST:

```
old = Old password 
new1 = New password 
new2 = Re-enter new Password
```

See the code in the web module for more info [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/338f8d843832c339c52c00c7f4c41b5ab2d696ed/addons/portal/controllers/portal.py#L203)

```
@route('/my/security', type='http', auth='user', website=True, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def security(self, **post):
    values = self._prepare_portal_layout_values()
    values['get_error'] = get_error

    if request.httprequest.method == 'POST':
        values.update(self._update_password(
            post['old'].strip(),
            post['new1'].strip(),
            post['new2'].strip()
        ))

    return request.render('portal.portal_my_security', values, headers={
        'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY'
    })
```

Comment: thank you @Amr Abd-Alkrim, will check this. will you please help me to inherit odoo's controller to add custom fields in SignUp form ( currently i have added in actual file which is not recommended, but added as i have no idea how to do it ). my problem is i have no background with this type of web application development, i have experience in oracle sql & pl/sql + Apex. you better knew the reality is the web development is far more different approach than oracle's products mentioned here. that's why mostly i failed to understand things.

Comment: Okay @Oralover i will give you more detailed answer if you modified your question or ask another question and tag me i will answer it there so people don't get confused

Comment: thanks, yeah this will be a seperate topic to understand 1 thing at a time clearly :)

Comment: i am ban for asking questions, this is my fault, i do not have idea to ask odoo related questions because of my knowledge level... it says "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Answer (score 1):

The payload for that purpose is:

```
{
    "params": {
        "fields": [
            {"name": "old_pwd", "value": "123456"},
            {"name": "new_password", "value": "654321"},
            {"name": "confirm_pwd", "value": "654321"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Tested in v15 but in v13 and v14 the code looks the same.

I hope this answer could help.